# Node.js could not read ok from ADB Server

Tags: node.js, adb

I had used Node.js to development apps, when I used `npx expo` this commend, but I got this error. I can't connecting to Android emulator.

```
Error: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb F 02-15 17:38:38 23712 23884 main.cpp:52] cannot open C:\Users\ABS\AppData\Local\Temp\adb.log: Permission denied
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Where am I missing to set up?

Comment: Did you try to run it with administrator?

Comment: @SashiKumar I can use android studio to open emulator, but I cannot directly use vscode to open it when I command npx expo

Comment: What about the file name mentioned? Does it exist? Can you delete the file? Is `ABS` the user name you are currently logged-in?

Comment: @Robert the file name is camping, its exist.  delete which file? yes, the user name is ABS

Comment: As the `adb.log` file is causing problems of course delete it, you will see if you can delete it. On windows "permission denied" often means that the file is opened (and thus locked) by a different process.

Answer (score 0):

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/+/HEAD/client/main.cpp#52
As someone commented, you're likely running into a write privilege issue (is your node.js module running under a different user?).
I would isolate the problem by running `adb kill-server && adb devices` in a terminal (and make sure it works, and then trouble-shoot node.js settings). This terminal windows does *not* need to run as Administrator.